# Yii dropdownList empty causing error

Tags: php, yii

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->order = 'type_name';
$models = Type::model()->findAll($criteria);
$list = CHtml::listData($models, 'typeid', 'type_name');

echo CHtml::dropDownList('DataSkema[typeid]', $model->typeid, $list, array(
    'empty'=>'--Pilih Jenis Lokasi--', // this line causing error, when I comment it out the error is not showing
    'id'=>'type-drop',
    'class'=>'form-control'
));
```

as explained in the code above, when i commented the line `echo cHtml::dropDownList()` the form is works well when submited. why and how to fix it?

here is the exception error

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "". The SQL statement executed was: SELECT * FROM "app_ref_location" "t" WHERE typeid=:typeid ORDER BY location_name
```

Comment: What happened if you change the `empty` key with `placeholder` ? Also, try to add one more value inside your `$list`. Something  like `$list[0] = ''`

Comment: i just wrote this and it worked 
`$form->dropDownList($model,'fk_branch_id',array(CHtml::listData(Branches::model()->findAll(array('condition'=>"branch_active = '1'", 'order'=>'branch_name ASC')), 'pk_branch_id', 'branch_name')), array('empty'=>'-= Please Select One =-', 'class'=>'form-control'));`

Comment: i realized that i hit a integer column with string, postgresql issue.